# Can't set my navigation bar background image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to change my table view navigation bar background image to some png, i created the nav bar png with the exact sizes of a default nav bar (I checked in interface builder).

This is my code (in my table view controller class, viewDidLoad method):

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav.png"];
[navBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Shouldn't this work..?

this is my table view settings in the interface builder if this help:

[image]
[image]

the top  one is what i suppose to get and the bottom one is what im getting:

[image]

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
UIImageView *backImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav.png"]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:backImgView];
```

Try to add Image in custom view

Comment: i added a photo - with your solution the top one is what i suppose to get and the bottom one is what im getting @Hemali Luhar

Comment: plus in your solution i can also change the size to 320w and 44h @Hemali Luhar

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the existing nav bar? Don t think you need to create a new one... This code is working for me :

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Your TableViewController must be "embadded" in a navigation controller a.k.a connected to other ViewControllers as push segue... Then you get your nav bar automatically instead of creating one... I mean you create a nav bar and never add it to the view isnt it?

Comment: i added a photo - with your solution the top one is what i suppose to get and the bottom one is what im getting @Kreuzberg